# Sci-fi / horror movie search - bus scene

Tags: story-identification, movie

It has been years of agony trying to find a sci-fi or horror movie I saw as child (around 8 or 9, so this was after 1998 for sure)

The only scenes I remember:

- a female character who is pregnant and driving a cab-taxi, coughing blood to a cloth
- said female character either giving birth or being attacted in a bus by/to a an alien - The alien was light colored, the sounds it made (just like a lot of other aliens) was in screeches of some kind. I recall it had slim tentacles, and it moved really fast

The woman was Caucasian and dark haired, I think in the taxi she was wearing a scarf but I am not sure

I don’t think this was a traditional b-movie, but I was probably 8 around that time, so the images are not clear.

This was somewhat scary and traumatic, so MiB is not an option.

Comment: I'm sure you can give us more detail. Was this a low budget b-movie type film? Was the female character caucasian or something else? What kind of bus was it? What size was the alien?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The woman was Caucasian and dark haired, I think in the taxi she was wearing a scarf but I am not sure. As I recall it I don’t think this was a traditional b-movie, but I was probably 8 around that time... The alien was light colored, the sounds it made (just like a lot of other aliens) was in screeches of some kind. I recall it had slim tentacles, and it moved really fast.

Comment: @prlirio - Great. Now [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/229145/edit) that into the question :-)

Comment: Which movies do you know for sure that are not answer?

Answer (score 5):

*[Baby Blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Blood)* (1990).

Pregnant lady drives a taxi pregnant. Then gives birth, but evil baby makes it to a bus and is taking over the driver.

> A snake-like parasite crawls into the uterus of an abused woman and circus performer named Yanka. The parasite demands human blood from Yanka who is first reluctant, but then finds that the only relationship she has is with the parasite. Yanka commits murders to devour the victims' blood in order to nurture the parasite. The parasite tells her that it is a creature that will replace man as the dominant species on the planet in five million years, and must be released in the ocean. The creature is eventually released in the sea where it abandons Yanka.

[image: creature baby shown]

[image: pregnant lady with scarf]

[[image: lady fighting the creature with bus driveryoutube video of movie recap]